# CoreBluetooth delegates on main queue/main thread?

Tags: objective-c, ios, multithreading, core-bluetooth

A queue is specified in the initialiser of CBCentralManager, `-initWithDelegate:queue:`.

From perspective of performance, is it better to schedule the Core Bluetooth delegates to a background thread/queue? Does UI operation, e.g. tracking a panning or zooming gesture, interfere with Bluetooth?

Comment: Great question. I never thought about using another queue but I noticed that the fastest message sending I could get is around 50 Hz (every 20ms); faster than that, it seems to get queued.

Comment: I first noticed about this when I was working on a previous project using External Accessory framework. I just wonder if it also matters using Core Bluetooth as well.

Answer (score 0):

the point of async callbacks is that they dont need to be scheduled because they get called when the heavy-work is over... of course when your delegate methods are heavy, this doesnt work anymore and it does make sense to move them to a different queue :)

OR if they are called 10000 times per secon. but apart from that, I dont think they need to be moved out of the main queue

Comment: You don't seem to understand my concerns. If you schedule some async callbacks to main thread, and when some UI things(, e.g. panning, dragging, zooming, events possibly in event tracking runloop mode) occupies the main thread, your callbacks would be delayed until these UI events are done.

Comment: why? are they long and blocking? dont think so.. you are right I did understand you wrong ^^ but now it seems .. weirder :D your views operation shouldnt block

Comment: @ZhangChn: were you able to solve your issue? I am going through the same problem as well.

I am able to setup the corebluetooth delegate on a separate thread but it is still invoking in the main thread... odd.

Answer (score 0):

Depending on how you are using CoreBluetooth, there may arrive *a lot* of callbacks per second, hence I strongly advise creating a dedicated (serial) dispatch queue to handle them in coordinated fashion.